# Numba @jit(nopython=True) function offers no speed improvement on heavy Numpy function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I am currently running `test_matrix_speed()` to see how fast my `search_and_book_availability` function is. Using the PyCharm profiler I can see that each `search_and_book_availability` function call averages a speed of 0.001ms.  Having the Numba `@jit(nopython=True)` decorator makes no difference to the performance of this function. Is this because there are no improvements to be had and Numpy is operating as fast as possible here? (I don't care about the speed of the `generate_searches` function)

Here's the code I'm running

```py
import random

import numpy as np
from numba import jit


def generate_searches(number, sim_start, sim_end):
    searches = []
    for i in range(number):
        start_slot = random.randint(sim_start, sim_end - 1)
        end_slot = random.randint(start_slot + 1, sim_end)
        searches.append((start_slot, end_slot))
    return searches


@jit(nopython=True)
def search_and_book_availability(matrix, search_start, search_end):
    search_slice = matrix[:, search_start:search_end]
    output = np.where(np.sum(search_slice, axis=1) == 0)[0]
    number_of_bookable_vecs = output.size
    if number_of_bookable_vecs > 0:
        if number_of_bookable_vecs == 1:
            id_to_book = output[0]
        else:
            id_to_book = np.random.choice(output)
        matrix[id_to_book, search_start:search_end] = 1
        return True
    else:
        return False


def test_matrix_speed():
    shape = (10, 1440)
    matrix = np.zeros(shape)
    sim_start = 0
    sim_end = 1440
    searches = generate_searches(1000000, sim_start, sim_end)
    for i in searches:
        search_start = i[0]
        search_end = i[1]
        availability = search_and_book_availability(matrix, search_start, search_end)
```

Comment: Is it important to randomly choose the booking (for instance to avoid adversarial user input) or would deterministically returning the first value do?

Comment: @Jatentaki - yes. The random selection is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your function and the following code to profile the speed

```
import time

shape = (10, 1440)
matrix = np.zeros(shape)
sim_start = 0
sim_end = 1440
searches = generate_searches(1000000, sim_start, sim_end)

def reset():
    matrix[:] = 0

def test_matrix_speed():
    for i in searches:
        search_start = i[0]
        search_end = i[1]
        availability = search_and_book_availability(matrix, search_start, search_end)

def timeit(func):
    # warmup
    reset()
    func()

    reset()
    start = time.time()
    func()
    end = time.time()

    return end - start

print(timeit(test_matrix_speed))
```

I find on the order of 11.5s for `jit`ed version and 7.5s without `jit`. I am no expert on numba, but what it is made for is optimizing numerical code written in non-vectorized way, in particular explicit `for` loops. In your code there is none, you only use vectorized operations. Therefore I expected `jit` to not outperform baseline solution, though I must admit that I am surprised to see it that much worse. If you're looking to optimize your solution, you can cut the execution time (at least on my PC) with the following code:

```
def search_and_book_availability_opt(matrix, search_start, search_end):
    search_slice = matrix[:, search_start:search_end]

    # we don't need to sum in order to check if all elements are 0.
    # ndarray.any() can use short-circuiting and is therefore faster.
    # Also, we don't need the selected values from np.where, only the
    # indexes, so np.nonzero is faster
    bookable, = np.nonzero(~search_slice.any(axis=1))

    # short circuit
    if bookable.size == 0:
        return False

    # we can perform random choice even if size is 1
    id_to_book = np.random.choice(bookable)
    matrix[id_to_book, search_start:search_end] = 1
    return True
```

and by initializing `matrix` as `np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool)`, instead of the default `float64`. I am able to get execution times of around 3.8s, a ~50% improvement over your unjited solution and ~70% improvement over the jited version. Hope that helps.